# htaccess redirect without directing the contents after the domain label (.com)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My question is quite simple, I need to accomplish the following:

**here.domain.com** -> **domain.com/here**

However, *I do not wish to include anything that appears after the domain label* (.com)

If a visitor requests **here.domain.com/something** it will remain as here.domain.com/something

Hope that makes sense, I tried this: but it has no conditional logic for testing for contents after top level of the domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^here\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /here/$1 [L]
```

Anyone knowledgeable enough to help with this teaser?